# AES Encryption in JAVA and InputStream

Tags: java, encryption, aes, inputstream

Sorry, JAVA beginner here. I was trying out some encryption decryption examples. My methods were supposed to be returning an InputStream and were also supposed to take in an Inputstream as a parameter.
The signature of the method looked like this,
`public static InputStream encriptFile(InputStream inputFile)`.
I researched a bit, and wrote some code confidently, but i don't think the code is properly encrypting a sample file because when I decrypt it and convert into string, it still shows me gibberish. I really don't know what's going wrong with encrypting and decrypting the InputStreams. The Java class looks like this,

```
    
    private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
    private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";
    
    /*
     * Getting a 128 bit key and iv for encryption
     */
    
    public static InputStream encriptFile(InputStream inputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        
        byte[] nonEncryptedByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputFile);
        
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec secretkey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); //Cipher instance using AES encryption algorithm
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey, iv);
        byte[] encryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(nonEncryptedByteArray);
        
        /*
         * Used the cipher library to encrypt the stream to a byte array
         */
        InputStream encryptedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedByteArray);
        
        /*
         * Back to streams, but this time encrypted
         */
        
        return encryptedInputStream;
    }
    
    public static InputStream decriptFile(InputStream inputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        
        byte[] encrytToDecryptByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputFile);
        
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec secretkey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretkey, iv);
        byte[] decryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(encrytToDecryptByteArray);
        
        /*
         * dencrypted the encrypted data
         */
        
        InputStream decryptedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedByteArray);
        
        return decryptedInputStream;
    }
```

The main method looks like this,

```
        
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        
        InputStream eis = encriptFile(is);
        
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(eis, writer, "UTF-8");
        String theString = writer.toString();
        
        System.out.print(theString);
```

The contents of the text file are "Hello, file to be encrypted. Let's see if this works.".

The output which should have printed out an encrypted output looks like this.
`��T��� ���N�?]�7!2`. When I go ahead and decrypt it, it still shows me gibberish. Sorry for the really long question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of `CipherInputStream`?

Comment: I am now lol. Thanks for the heads up @MarquisofLorne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not return input streams at all. And the way you are using the streams, you're not actually streaming. If you have to use a stream, use `CipherInputStream`. Personally I'd always use `CipherOutputStream` for encryption and `CipherInputStream` for decryption (you are not likely to do anything with the encrypted data, after all, other than exporting it from your application).

A cipher furthermore returns binary data. That's not the same as UTF-8, and no encoding should be necessary for files either, as they accept binary data directly. This is likely the current problem. Just use `FileOutputStream` / `FileInputStream` instead of writers or readers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Appreciate it. Will use CipherInputStream for future encryption related activities.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and I think you are printing the encrypted value (so, gibberish) and not the decrypted.

If you update the `main` to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));

    InputStream eis = encriptFile(is);

    InputStream result = decriptFile(eis); // <-- Decryption here

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(result, writer, "UTF-8");
    String theString = writer.toString();

    System.out.print(theString);
}
```

You should be fine.

I tested just by changing the `decryptFile()` method to:

```
public static InputStream decriptFile(InputStream inputFile) throws Exception {

    byte[] encrytToDecryptByteArray = new byte[inputFile.available()];
    inputFile.read(encrytToDecryptByteArray);

    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    SecretKeySpec secretkey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CBC_PKCS_5_PADDING);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretkey, iv);
    byte[] decryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(encrytToDecryptByteArray);

    System.out.println(new String(decryptedByteArray));

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedByteArray);
}
```

And calling it with the result from the `encriptFile()` and it worked properly.

Comment: Thanks. Really helps

Comment: np. Please take a look at @Maarten answer for a more holistic, clean and secure solution.